# Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hello i have a problem and i need some help
i want to integrate facebook Sdk in my project to facebook ads to get installs and i got some errors

This is the error :

> Error:Execution failed for task'
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/media/TransportPerformer.class

And this is my build.gradle code :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call}
}
`repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')

    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')

    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run './gradlew clean' in your project?